# appending "https:" to links in a soup which start with src=//

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, code-formatting

First i webscrape using beautiful soup

```
answers = soup.select('body > div.chg-body.no-nav.no-subnav.header-nav > div.chg-container.center-content > div.chg-container-content > div.chg-global-content > div > div.parent-container.question-headline > div.main-content.question-page > div.dialog-question > div.answers-wrap > ul > li > div > div.txt-body.answer-body > div.answer-given-body.ugc-base')
```

After webscraping i get my scraped data, but in that scraped data some links are like this:

```
src="//d2vlcm61l7u1fs.cloudfront.net/media%2F54b%2F54b505c2-d4e1-4745-8ab3-572866550500%2FphpvfFCYU.png"
```

The images don't show on the html page after i save the scraped data as html because it starts with //
.
How to append `https:` and check if url has `https`

[this is how the html document looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wc9PW.jpg)

please help to check if the urls in scraped data start with https and if not append "https:"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.startswith()` to check, if the `src` attribute starts with "//", and if yes, then add 'https:'.

For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_text = '''
    <div>
        <img src="//d2vlcm61l7u1fs.cloudfront.net/media%2F54b%2F54b505c2-d4e1-4745-8ab3-572866550500%2FphpvfFCYU.png" />
    </div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'html.parser')

for img in soup.select('img'):
    if img['src'].startswith('//'):
        print('https:' + img['src'])
    else:
        print(img['src'])
```

Prints:

```
https://d2vlcm61l7u1fs.cloudfront.net/media%2F54b%2F54b505c2-d4e1-4745-8ab3-572866550500%2FphpvfFCYU.png
```